# How to import #define constants from .h file to Ada?

Tags: c, constants, ada

I'm trying to move a constant from C to Ada that is located in a header file.

*file.h*

```
#define TEST 0x1234
```

How would I export this constant to ada? I know to export functions and import them into ada but I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing for constants.

Comment: Technically this is not a constant, it's a macro.

Comment: You can't "export" these as they are not in the compiled binary at all.

Comment: `TEST : constant Integer := 4660;`

Comment: Is there a way to make a constant equal to the macro and then export that to ada? How would I export and import that?

Comment: Are you using `gcc -c -fdump-ada-spec` for the rest of your low level binding? The way I've handled this is to add a second package for the bits the automatic binding generator doesn't handle ... here I'd put `TEST : constant Integer := 16#1234#;` in that second package.

Comment: I'm currently using an .ads for c imports and a .h for c exports.

Comment: `Test : constant := 16#1234#;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you’re asking how to write an Ada representation of this constant by hand, then the answer is

```ada
TEST : constant := 16#1234#;
```

If you want to maintain the relationship between the C and the Ada automatically, you can get `gcc` (or, better, `g++`; see at end) to do the grunt work. Given `sterisk.hh` containing your example,

```c
#define TEST 0x1234
```

compile it with

```ada
g++ -c -fdump-ada-spec sterisk.hh
```

which generates in `sterisk_hh.ads`

```ada
pragma Ada_2005;
pragma Style_Checks (Off);

with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package sterisk_hh is

   TEST : constant := 16#1234#;  --  sterisk.hh:1

end sterisk_hh;
```

A third way would be to create a small C source which includes the header (here C is better; you don’t want the name to be mangled in the object file) in say `sterisk.c`:

```c
#include "sterisk.hh"

const int _name_thats_unlikely_to_clash = TEST;
```

and compile to `sterisk.o`:

```ada
gcc -c sterisk.c
```

Then, in your Ada source:

```ada
Test : constant Integer
with
  Import,
  External_Name => "_name_thats_unlikely_to_clash";
```

Of course, this way means you have to decide on a specific type for the constant, and it has to match the C type.

Also, you need to include the C object file in your link:

```ada
gnatmake foo.adb -largs sterisk.o
```

---

Why is `g++` better than `gcc`? Because `g++` preserves more of the names in the C source, for example parameter names in functions.

Comment: Is there an alternative using export and import pragmas for c and ada respectively?

Comment: See mods in answer about compiling the C source & including in the link.